# how to check for irreducibility

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, function-fields

This might be a simple question, but I'm stuck. What is meant by  $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is a  polynomial over $F_{p^l}(t)$., which  is a function finite field, how to check for irreducibility?

Does there exist a Eisenstein criteria for irreducibility over function fields?

What is the role of variable $t$.

Comment: Consider $b^2-4ac$.

Comment: You could consider $f(x,y)$ as a polynomial in $F[y][x]$ and treat $f(x,y)$ as a polynomial in $x$ whose coefficients are polynomials in $y$. Then irreducibles in $F[y]$ are the replacement for prime numbers. But from that viewpoint $f(x,y)$ is not Eisenstein at $y$.  I suspect what you write as $Fp^t$ should be $F_{p^t}$, a finite field of order $p^t$.

Comment: @ KCd, I'm extremely sorry. It should have been $F_{p^{l}}(t)$.

Comment: I would like to check for irreducibility of $f(x,y)$ over $F_{p^{l}}(t)$. I do not know where to insert the variable $ 't'$

Comment: Are the coefficients $a,b,c$ coming from the function field $K=\Bbb{F}_{q}(t)$, $q$ a power of some prime? And you are asking about irreducibility in the ring $K[x,y]$? Otherwise I don't see a role for $t$ to play?

Comment: YES coefficents a,b,c are from $F_{q^{l}}(t)$. and irreducibility over $K[x,y]$

Comment: Ok. Then you can take advantage homogeneity and might as well study irreducibility of $f(x,1)$ in $K[x]$ (assuming $a\neq0$). Which brings us to Lord Shark's hint. If the discriminant is a square, then... Anyway, in $K[x]$ Eisenstein's criterion applies as follows. You can clear the denominators and assume that the coefficients are polynomials in $t$. Then irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q[t]$ are used exactly as primes in Eisenstein's criterion. In addition to that we have the "infinite" prime.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, Thank you very much  for the answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, where do I get some material  to check irreducibles ( by Eisenstein criteria) over polynomial ring with more than 2 variables. I do not know much about this subject. thank you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, could you make your comment as answer, so that this question remains away from not answered. Thank you. also, what is the role of infinite prime here.

Comment: Unless no one else bites I will. But it will have to wait for a few hours. Deadline. Actually already passed, but still urgent :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Does the above described method apply, if one wants to check for irreducibility in $K[x,y,t]$, given the problem as above?